# SCCM and USMT does not perform well

Tags: windows

Have just succeeded in setting up a State migration point on our SCCM and after that got USMT to make user profile backup and restore on the reinstalled PC.

According to the log everything is OK and User data and desktop is there but hardly anything else , not even my Edge favorites or any browser favorites.
USMT is the latest 20H2

Is this what to expect or is something wrong?

Comment: Just do what Thomas says :-D No seriously, he definitely knows what he talks about when it comes to User migrations. Also consider using his tools for migrations in stead of SCCM.
They give you a lot more control :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know. Disapointing but it is only a question about updates.
Please get my EhlerTech updated [custom xml files](https://ehlertech.com) for USMT and include them in your SCCM USMT package.
Basically just use MigUser.xml, MigApp.xml and Win10.xml from my xml package.

- In case you only need the users profile without scanning the rest of the drive for docs, use MigUser_Profile_only.xml (faster but only grabs data inside the user profiles)

To see a more thorough XML guide [go here :-)](http://usmtgui.com/Description%20of%20EhlerTech%20XML%20files.pdf)

/Thomas